# Checking If Email Exists In Database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, validation

I am checking if an e-mail exists in the database when a user is signing up for a new account. The "EmailMessage" is not coming up when I put in an e-mail that is in the database. Code located below:

validateemail.js

```
function validateemail() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
    else
     {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {

            var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
            response = response.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'')

            if(response == 'error'){
                document.getElementById("EmailMessage").innerHTML='This e-mail address is already taken! If you believe this is in error,  please email <a href="mailto:support@pumpspy.com">support@pumpspy.com</a>';
                document.getElementById("newemail").focus();
                document.getElementById("email_notice").style.display="none";
                document.getElementById("submit_new_account").disabled =true;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("EmailMessage").innerHTML="";

            }
        }
      }
    var newemail = document.getElementById("newemail").value;


    if(newemail!=""){
        xmlhttp.open("GET","Checkemail.php?email="+newemail,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    else{
        document.getElementById("EmailMessage").innerHTML="";

        document.getElementById("submit_new_account").disabled =false;
        }


}
```

Checkemail.php

```
    $emailexists = $_GET['email'];

    $sql = executeQuery("SELECT email from tbl_Users WHERE email = '$emailexists'");
    $i = getNumRows($sql);  

     if ($i !=0)    {
         echo "error";          
    }else {
             echo "pass"; 

    }

---



    <input type="text" id="newemail" name="newemail" maxlength="60" size="27" onblur="validateemail();"/>
        </div>
        <div id="EmailMessage" style="color:#F00"></div>
```

Comment: Have you narrowed this down any? Can you call the PHP directly with an email address, and get the right response?

Comment: I get "error" when I do

Comment: So the next step is to `var_dump($sql)` and `var_dump($i)` to see what values are in there. Presumably your query is failing for some reason.

Comment: @andrewsi error bool(true) int(1) when i put in an e-mail that was in the database. $sql is true and $i is 1

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.fcom/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @andrewsi: _“It doesn’t work”_ is what counts as _narrowing it down_ for a lot of people … sadly.

Comment: @ChaseC - so you put in an email that exists; see that `$i` is set to 1. Your database is returning 1 row - so have a look at your `if` statement that's returning the string.

Comment: @CBroe - at least this chap included the code without having to be asked.

Comment: @andrewsi Yeah in my code I want to display the EmailMessage and focus on the "newemail" input to make sure they insert an e-mail that doesn't exist. And I also disable them being able to submit the form.

Comment: @ChaseC - OK. If the email address is in the database, then you have a value of 1 in `$i`. Look at your `if` statement. What does it return if `$i` is 1?

Answer (score 0):

Try: `$sql = executeQuery("SELECT email from tbl_Users WHERE email = '".$emailexists."'");`

Also, please consider changing your code completely (concerns, security issues)...

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference - the string is already double-quoted, so it'll interpolate variables without having to explicitly concatenate

Comment: Urgh, you are right! Not sure what I was thinking. Most likely got confused with `'` and interpolated quotes in my mind.